# denormalizing with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

What is the best way to de-normalize with mongoid and Rails?

Using the "embedded" relationships does not appear to work (or be intended for anything but embedding the entire, original documents).

My present solution stores and retrieved the de-normalized attributes as an OrderedHash:

```
collection.update({_id: id, ...}, {..., denormalized: {_id: other.id, _type: other._type, a: other.a, b: other.b}}

def denormalized
  Mongoid::Factory.build(attributes[:denormalized]["_type"], attributes[:denormalized])
end
```

edit: I should mention that I did try https://github.com/logandk/mongoid_denormalize

It flattens out the denormalized attributes (in the example below, it would store author_name instead of author: {name: "value"} and it doesn't have support for multiple denormalized relations (e.g. authors: [{name: "First Co-Author", _id: 1}, {name: "Second Co-Author", _id: 2}])

edit: An example was requested.

```
class User # this class uses STI so _type field is important
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :name # this is the field I want to de-normalize to where Users are referenced

   def write_book
     Book.create!({title: "Some Text", author: {_id: self.id, _type: self._type, name: self.name})
   end
end

class Book
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :title

  # embeds_one :author, polymorphic: true
  # tried this but it doesn't seem to be correct usage... it sort of works but
  # I run into problems with cycles and infinite loops when used extensively
  # because (I think) of how mongoid works internally, expecting embeds_one
  # to mean something different

  def author
    Mongoid::Factory.build(attributes[:author]["_type"], attributes[:author])
  end
end
```

The correct solution would have ActiveModel methods such as new_record? working as well as the *_path and *_url routing helpers.

Comment: Can you add an example what do you want to denormalize?

Comment: edited original post to provide example

Comment: Another example (taken from MongoDB in Action, p62) would be an e-commerce order.  You would denormalize the shipping address, and the items/prices.  How would that be accomplished in Mongoid?

Answer (score -1):

This will store the user as an embedded author document inside the book.

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
end

#instead of the write book method, you could just do this:
book = Book.create(title: "Old Man And The Sea", users: [user])

class Book
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :authors

  field :title

  def users=(users)
    users.each do |user|
      authors.build(user: user, name: user.name)
    end
  end
end

class Author
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :book
  referenced_in :user

  field :name
end
```

Comment: I'm not seeing where the User's name would be denormalized into the book document.